# Why do we need to generate synthetic data based on complex probability distributions rather than just repeating input data over and over again?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

For research purposes, we are sometimes required to do analysis on synthetic datasets generated by complex procedures based on probability distributions of the seed data. The validation of these procedures is usually done by comparing the summary statistics of the real world source data and the output synthetic data.

I was just curious, if we have a real world seed data, why don't we just repeat the data over and over again to create a bigger synthetic data? Wouldn't that also share the same statistics metrics? I am sure there is some mathematical theory behind this, but I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: +1 It would be wonderful if we could do this.  Think of the time and money that would be saved! For instance, to conduct a high-precision national opinion poll you would no longer have to contact thousands of people; instead, you could just ask a question of two friends, then multiply their answers by a thousand.

Comment: Well, I feel this is not a valid comparison to my question. Synthetic datasets are created not from a small sample space of 10 or 15, but from samples which go beyond hundreds and thousands.

Comment: I may have a different understanding than you intended by "repeat the data over and over again."  I took that to mean duplicating the data records.  In your post, could you clarify what that process is?

Comment: I meant duplicating it only. But duplicating about 1000s of records and not just 10-20 of them as is mentioned in your comparison of 'duplication' in opinion polls.

Comment: There appears to be no difference in procedure between duplicating thousands of records or duplicating just two.  Exactly where is the line that divides those cases?

Answer (score 2):

Synthetic data is used for testing and evaluating systems for which data can and will change in the future, although the distribution may remain the same. If you keep duplicating, the expected output might not differ at all.

For example:

1. You used data that concluded "Percentage of people earning above XYZ$ is 5%".
2. If you kept duplicating, it will remain the same.
3. If you use the same distribution and generated a new set of data, the percentage will vary with the change in sample size.